# How to make a section as big as its background image so to show it in its entirety?

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image in its full size in a section on my website with nothing over it.
So I created an empty section and set it as background then put a column plus a transparent element then setting padding and margin.

I'm attaching an image of the way it looks right now.
They are two sections (the one above is just for a reference. And not in the code)

Where the image is is a empty section with only background and it's the section I want to make as big as the image. Right now as you can see it's cut.

[image]

**How can I make the size of the section as big as its background without having to put elements inside of it and using code?**

I'm sure there must be a better way by using CSS.

```html
<div class="content content--padding-large" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0px;" id="_2odptjbtq">
        <div class="background_changer background_changer--blur0 js-bg-next-gen" alt="" style="opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/15398563_1607856820728Background.webp&quot;);" data-bg="url(&quot;//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/15398563_1607856820728Background.webp" data-was-processed="true"></div>
        <div class="background_changer_overlay" style="background-image: none;"></div>
        <div class="container">
            
            
        <div class="row background_changer--blur0" data-component="grid" alt="" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; background-image: none; opacity: 1;"><div class="col-md-12 colView"><div class="js_kartra_component_holder">
<div data-component="divider">                            
    <hr class="kartra_divider kartra_divider--border-extra-tiny kartra_divider--border-dim-black-opaque-25 pull-center kartra_divider--full" style="border-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0); border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; margin: 80px 0px 55px;">
</div>
<div data-component="divider">                            
    <hr class="kartra_divider kartra_divider--border-small kartra_divider--border-royal-blue-two pull-center kartra_divider--full" style="border-color: rgba(49, 110, 212, 0); border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 5px; margin: 0px;">
</div>
</div></div></div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please add your code snippets so that we could assist you.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: You could also try something like min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; for the styling

Comment: @coderboy thanks for the tip. I just shared it.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this style to it

`style="min-width: 100%!important; max-width: 100%!important;"`